# Is the space generated by $f(x)=\sin(x)$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my textbook it says that set of all the functions on a given interval is a vector space.
Does that mean that space generated by any function is a vector space?
If not then explain what it means with example.
If yes then how can one say that space generated by $\sin(x)$ is  a vector space because it's not closed under multiplication
$\sin(90)=1$
so $1$ belongs to vector space
$10*\sin(90)=10$ should also belong to vector space but it does not.

Comment: What you have proved is that $\sin(x)$ itself is not a linear function (obviously :)). However, as the answers below note, your textbook is referring to a function in an abstract sense, see the answer by @Eemil Wallin, because that's the real test.

Comment: What do you mean by "space generated" if you don't know you are already dealing with a vector space

Answer (score 1):

The vector space generated by $\sin{x}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ in the sense you mention would be
$$ \{ k\sin{x} : k \in \mathbb{R} \}. $$
It is isomorphic as a vector space to $\mathbb{R}$ by the linear map $k \sin{x} \mapsto k $.

What the book should actually mean is that
$$ \{ f : (f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} ) \} $$
is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. This is easy to check: clearly if $f,g$ are such functions, and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$ a f + b g $$
is another such function.

Answer (score 0):

Your textbook probably refers to that the set of all functions on a given interval span an abstract vector space, for example,

$f(x)+g(x)$ is closed under addition, $a*(f(x)+g(x)) = af(x)+ag(x)$.

Comment: It is used by some authors to denote vector spaces which have elements that are not scalars, I've encountered the term in "Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms". Also mathworld has a definition of it: [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbstractVectorSpace.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up functions and their values at certain points. $\sin$ is a function while $\sin(90)$ is just a real number. This being said, you can easily define the sum of two functions by setting
$$(f+g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$$
and
$$(r \cdot f)(x) := r \cdot f(x)$$
for all $x \in D(f) \cap D(g)$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $f+g$ and $r \cdot f$ are also functions and the set of functions on a given interval is a vector space (with neutral element $f \equiv 0$).

If you just take $f = \sin$ then you generate a 1-dimensional subspace of the space of all functions. This again is a vector space. In particular you have

$$< \sin > = \{ r \cdot \sin : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $X$ is a vector space and $x$, the "space generated by $x$" is

> The smallest subspace $Y\subset X$ such that $x\in Y$.

Therefore, by **definition**, the space generated by a particular function is a vector space.

---

This may be confusing to you, but you must understand that the space, generated by the function $\sin x$, is in fact the set of functions:

$$\{x\mapsto \alpha\cdot \sin(x)| \alpha\in \mathbb R\}$$

Therefore, the function $f(x)=10\sin x$ is also an element of the space, generated by $\sin$

Answer (score -1):

It means that the set of functions $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ has domain and range $a$ is a vector space with vector addition defined as the composition of functions. $f(x)= \sin (x)$ is not a vector spaces for the reason you gave.

Comment: Why would the composition of functions be invertible?

Comment: Composition is wrong - composition of functions is not abelian.

Comment: The operations on this vector space are function addition and scalar multiplication, so you really only have things like $v(x)=a\sin x$ for any $a\in R$. Just like if you took the vector $(0,1)$ in $R^{2}$ and obtained a vector space by considering all vectors of varying lengths but in the same or opposite direction as $(0,1)$.